# Flag comment box overflowing on Chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Using 10.0.648.205

[image: comment overflow]

Comment: Might be a generic WebKit/Mac OS X issue: I see this in builds of Safari as well.

Comment: I'm looking into this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.